# Django rest how to do not send specific data of the serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example, I would like to send user information with `serializer.data` response, where the serializer has:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'passwordHash', 'email')
```

How can I send the serialized user without the `passwordHash` field of the serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't include 'passwordHash':
`fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')`

or set it to write-only:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'passwordHash', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'passwordHash': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

Comment: That's another way of doing it

Comment: But `read_only_fields` are sent with the serializer, how can i combine both?